Voltage spike comparison between SiC MOSFET and Si MOSFET? Which one is the lowest?
Under identical conditions (same circuit, switching frequency, PCB layout, etc.), is there a difference in the voltage spikes during turn-off between SiC MOSFETs and Si MOSFETs? Generally speaking, can it be said that SiC MOSFETs produce lower voltage spikes compared to Si MOSFETs?

FETs don't produce voltage spikes, the surrounding circuit does. You might want to specify the surrounding circuit.

Under identical conditions, an SiC MOSFET might explode from insufficient drive strength, or do nothing at all; or the Si MOSFET might explode from excessive Vgs(on). How are we to resolve the differences between any possible device?

@TimWilliams Assume both semiconductors are driven smoothly by the same gate driver. In practice, there are many examples of this. For systems using Si MOSFETs or IGBTs, manufacturers often recommend pin-to-pin compatible SiC MOSFET models.

Well, again, which ones? The switching gate voltages of any possible Si and SiC parts, have some overlap, but many parts are strictly incompatible. What's stopping me from comparing a logic-level or depletion Si MOSFET to a SiC MOSFET that requires 20V Vgs(on)? What about PMOS?  Or -- is outlining that distinction intended as part of the question?


Generally speaking, can it be said that SiC MOSFETs produce lower voltage spikes compared to Si MOSFETs?

I'd say "no", or at least "depends on the device".
The spikes depend on the \$di/dt\$ which relates to the switching speed, NOT directly the switching frequency i.e. the quicker the current is stopped, the higher the spike is produced. This can easily be seen from \$V_L=L \ di/dt\$. Therefore, with the same drive pulse (i.e. same amplitude and rise/fall times) and the same "surroundings" (e.g. parasitics such as total inductance along the way), the one switching quicker than the other will produce higher spike.
Switching speed depends on several parameters such as input capacitance Ciss (equals to CGS+CGD), total gate resistance (equals to the sum of the external gate stopper resistance and the internal/intrinsic gate resistance Rgg or RG), and in some applications (e.g. resonant converters) the output capacitance Coss which equals to CDS + CGD (Ignoring the effect of internal bonding inductances).

ImgSrc
From the driver, the MOSFET is seen as a capacitance (input capacitance of the MOSFET) so the quicker the input capacitance is charged or discharged, the quicker the MOSFET switches. But keep the gate plateau in mind, especially for turn on.
One thing worth to note here is that, amongst the same-size and similar-spec Si and SiC MOSFETs, SiC ones generally have smaller input capacitance but the internal gate resistance can be higher. For example, this SiC MOSFET has less than half the input capacitance and but double the gate resistance compared to this Si MOSFET whilst both are in the same package, rated for 650-700 V and have fairly close on-state resistances. Another two examples are this SiC MOSFET and this Si MOSFET with fairly close general specs.
From here, it's not possible to make a general conclusion as "A SiC device switches slower therefore produces less spike".

As you mentioned, the parasitic capacitance and inductance of an SiC MOSFET are lower. You talked about capacitance, which, as you said, reduces the turn-on and turn-off times. However, a reduction in parasitic inductance also lowers the voltage stress on the switch. The stray inductance comes from both the PCB layout and the semiconductor package.
My question is: if we keep the same PCB layout, won’t the reduction in parasitics from the semiconductor itself help us achieve the same or even lower voltage spikes as with an Si MOSFET, compensating for the faster switching?

@Multicharger SiC or Si, a MOSFET's parasitic inductances mainly come from the package. If it's an SMD MOSFET, the drain and source stray inductances can vary between 1~2 to 5~6 nH as the leg length increases (SO/DFN has the lowest, DPAK and D2PAK has the highest). If it's a TO-220 package it gets even higher as the effective leg length can be longer. So it comes down to the PCB layout anyways. From the design and manufacturing, there could be a difference between a Si and SiC in terms of stray inductances but I don't believe the difference will be that much.

Could you recommend a reference source or article on this topic?

@Multicharger "Effect of Source Inductance on MOSFET Rise and Fall Times" from Alan Elbanhawy.
